# Problemas com Roleta de Cassino

Tags: java

Meu professor de programação pediu que fizéssemos uma roleta de cassino que tivesse a opção de jogar roleta americana, europeia e francesa.

Porém após algumas alterações que fiz no código quando digito o nome do primeiro jogador não aparece mais nada, alguém sabe como resolvo isso?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Jogo {

public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Jogador[] jogadores = new Jogador[2];

//--------------------------------------
    //-------PRENCHER O ARRAY--------
    for(int i=0; i < jogadores.length;i++){
        if(jogadores[i]== null){
            System.out.println("Deseja adicionar jogador? sim ou não");
            while(input.next().equals("sim")){
                System.out.println("Digite um nome");
                String nome = input.next();
                Jogador J = new Jogador(nome);
                jogadores[i] = J;

            }
        }
    }
    //----------SABER SE JOGADORES QUEREM APOSTAR OU NÃO------------
    for(int i=0; i < jogadores.length;i++){
        if(jogadores[i]!=null){
            System.out.println(jogadores[i].getNome()+ " Deseja apostar? sim ou não");
            if(input.next().equals("sim")){ // quer apostar
                apostar(jogadores[i]);                  
            }else 
                if(jogadores[i].getSemapostas()==3){
                    System.out.println("Você esta sem apostar a tres rodadas");
                    apostar(jogadores[i]);
                }else
                    jogadores[i].SemApostar();
        }
    }
    Rodar(jogadores);

}


//@overwarnigs(ressources);
    //----------APOSTAR--------------
    private static void apostar(Jogador J){

        Banca banc = new Banca();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(J.getFichas()>0){ //verificar fichas suficientes
            System.out.println("Apostar");
            System.out.println("--------");
            System.out.println("par ou impar\npreto ou vermelho\nnumero\nmaior ou menor");
            String aposta = input.next();
            J.setAposta(aposta);

            System.out.println("Insere o valor (número de fichas)");
            J.setFichasApostadas(input.nextInt());
            banc.ganharDoJogador(J.getFichasApostadas());
            if(J.getAposta().equals("numero")){
                System.out.println("Qual número deseja apostar?");
                J.setNumeroAposta(input.nextInt());
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Rodar(Jogador[] jogadores){
        Roleta rol = new Roleta();
        Banca banc = new Banca();
        rol.rodar();
        int numero = rol.getNumero();
        String cor = rol.getCor();
        for (int i =0;i<jogadores.length;i++){
            Jogador JG = jogadores[i];
//----------------------------------PAR------------------------------------------------
            if(JG.getAposta().equals("par")) // caso "PAR"

                    if((numero>0 && (numero%2)==0)){ // acertou
                        if(banc.getBudget()>= JG.getFichasApostadas()*2){// verifique o budget da banca (Suficiente)
                            banc.pagarJogador(JG.getFichasApostadas()*2);// Atualise o budget da banca
                            JG.ganharFichas(JG.getFichasApostadas()*2); //pagar jogador
                            System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                            System.out.println(numero);
                            System.out.println(JG.getNome() + " acertou");
                            System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                        }else                               // verifique o budget da banca (Insuficiente)
                            System.out.println(JG.getNome() + " quebrou a banca");
                    }
                    else{                           //não acertou
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                        System.out.println(numero);
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome() + " não acertou");
                        System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                    }


//----------------------------------IMPAR------------------------------------------------
            if(JG.getAposta().equals("impar")) // caso "IMPAR"


                    if((numero>0 && (numero%2)==1)){ // acertou
                        if(banc.getBudget()>= JG.getFichasApostadas()*2){// verifique o budget do banco (Suficiente)
                            banc.pagarJogador(JG.getFichasApostadas()*2);// Atualise o budget do banco
                            JG.ganharFichas(JG.getFichasApostadas()*2); //paga jogador
                            System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                            System.out.println(numero);
                            System.out.println(JG.getNome() +" acertou");
                            System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                        }else                               // verifique o budget do banco (Insuficiente)
                            System.out.println(JG.getNome() + " deixou a banca pobre");
                    }
                    else{                           //não acertou
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                        System.out.println(numero);
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome() +" não acertou");
                        System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                    }


//----------------------------------VERMELHO------------------------------------------------
            if(JG.getAposta().equals("vermelho")) // caso "VERMELHO"

                    if(cor.equals("vermelho")){ // acertou
                        if(banc.getBudget()>= JG.getFichasApostadas()*2){// verifique o budget do banco (Suficiente)
                            banc.pagarJogador(JG.getFichasApostadas()*2);// Atualise o budget do banco
                            JG.ganharFichas(JG.getFichasApostadas()*2); //paga joador
                            System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                            System.out.println(numero + " "+cor);
                            System.out.println(JG.getNome() + " acertou");
                            System.out.println("-------------------------");
                            System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                        }else                               // verifique o budget do banco (Insuficiente)
                            System.out.println(JG.getNome() + " deixou a banca pobre");

                    }
                    else{                           //não acertou
                        banc.ganharDoJogador(JG.getFichasApostadas());
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                        System.out.println(numero + " "+cor);
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome() +" não acertou");
                        System.out.println("-------------------------");
                        System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                    }

//----------------------------------PRETO------------------------------------------------
            if(JG.getAposta().equals("preto")) // caso "PRETO"

                    if(cor.equals("preto")){ // acertou
                        if(banc.getBudget()>= JG.getFichasApostadas()*2){// verifique o budget do banco (Suficiente)
                            banc.pagarJogador(JG.getFichasApostadas()*2);// Atualise o budget do banco
                            JG.ganharFichas(JG.getFichasApostadas()*2); //paga joador
                            System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                            System.out.println(numero + " "+cor);
                            System.out.println(JG.getNome() +" acertou");
                            System.out.println("-------------------------");
                            System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                        }else                               // verifique o budget do banco (Insuficiente)
                            System.out.println(JG.getNome() +" deixou a banca pobre");

                    }
                    else{                           //não acertou
                        banc.ganharDoJogador(JG.getFichasApostadas());
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                        System.out.println(numero + " "+cor);
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome() +" não acertou");
                        System.out.println("-------------------------");
                        System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                    }


//----------------------------MENOR------------------------
            if(JG.getAposta().equals("menor")) // caso "MENOR"

                if(numero>= 1 && numero<19){ // acertou
                    if(banc.getBudget()>= JG.getFichasApostadas()*2){// verifique o budget do banco (Suficiente)
                        banc.pagarJogador(JG.getFichasApostadas()*2);// Atualise o budget do banco
                        JG.ganharFichas(JG.getFichasApostadas()*2); //paga joador
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                        System.out.println(numero);
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome() +" acertou");
                        System.out.println("-------------------------");
                        System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                    }
                    else                                // verifique o budget do banco (Insuficiente)
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome() + " deixou a banca pobre");

                }
                else{                           //não acertou
                    banc.ganharDoJogador(JG.getFichasApostadas());
                    System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                    System.out.println(numero);
                    System.out.println(JG.getNome() +" não acertou");
                    System.out.println("-------------------------");
                    System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                }

//----------------------------MAIOR------------------------
            if(JG.getAposta().equals("maior")) // caso "MAIOR"

                if(numero>= 19 && numero<37){ // acertou
                    if(banc.getBudget()>= JG.getFichasApostadas()*2){// verifique o budget do banco (Suficiente)
                        banc.pagarJogador(JG.getFichasApostadas()*2);// Atualise o budget do banco
                        JG.ganharFichas(JG.getFichasApostadas()*2); //paga joador
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                        System.out.println(numero);
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome() +" acertou");
                        System.out.println("-------------------------");
                        System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                    }
                    else                                // verifique o budget do banco (Insuficiente)
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome() +" deixou a banca pobre");

                }
                else{                           //não acertou
                    banc.ganharDoJogador(JG.getFichasApostadas());
                    System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                    System.out.println(numero);
                    System.out.println(JG.getNome() +" não acertou");
                    System.out.println("-------------------------");
                    System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                }

//----------------------------NUMERO--------------------------------------
            if(JG.getAposta().equals("numero")) // caso "NUMERO"

                if(numero == JG.getNumeroAposta()){ // acertou
                    if(banc.getBudget()>= JG.getFichasApostadas()*36){// verifique o budget do banco (Suficiente)
                        banc.pagarJogador(JG.getFichasApostadas()*36);// Atualise o budget do banco
                        JG.ganharFichas(JG.getFichasApostadas()*36); //paga joador

                        System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                        System.out.println(numero);
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome() +" acertou");
                        System.out.println("-------------------------");
                        System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                    }
                    else                                // verifique o budget do banco (Insuficiente)
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome() +" deixou a banca pobre");

                }//fim do if num
                else{                           //não acertou
                    banc.ganharDoJogador(JG.getFichasApostadas());
                    System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                    System.out.println(numero);
                    System.out.println(JG.getNome() +" não acertou");
                    System.out.println("-------------------------");
                    System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                }   //fim do else de numero
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: E a ruleta russa ? :D

Comment: Meu conselho é que você rode isso em uma IDE como o NetBeans ou Eclipse no modo Debug, para ver o caminho de execução do seu codigo. E adicione um breakpoint onde você acha que está dando problema.

Comment: Fiz isso e ele me disse que preciso fechar os input mas qdo faço isso nao aparece nada quando executo o codigo

Comment: Porque você não usa `System.console().readLine();` ?

Comment: Tenta fazer um do while, separe seu codigo para ter certeza que a função que pega do console está sendo chamada.

Comment: Outra coisa que percebi, vendo o codigo é que você já possui um tamanho fixo de jogadores, se você quer adicionar tantos jogadores quanto você não é melhor fazer uma ArrayList? Só comentando.

Comment: @ViniciusMorais Obrigado pelas dicas,eu não conhecia o System.console().readLine(); mas agora tentarei usar.Sobre o array list eu devo fazer tipo assim?:
`ArrayList<String> jogadores = new ArrayList<String> ();`

Answer (score 2):

## Entendendo o seu problema

Vamos ver esse trecho:

```
    for(int i=0; i < jogadores.length;i++){
        if(jogadores[i]== null){
            System.out.println("Deseja adicionar jogador? sim ou não");
            while(input.next().equals("sim")){
                System.out.println("Digite um nome");
                String nome = input.next();
                Jogador J = new Jogador(nome);
                jogadores[i] = J;

            }
        }
    }
```

Primeiro, que nesse ponto o `if` sempre é verdadeiro. Logo é desnecessário.

Observe que temos um `while` dentro de um `for`. O `for` percorre o array de jogadores. Já o `while` faz o que? Preenche **o mesmo** jogador diversas vezes. Não deve ser isso que você quer. Então recomendo que o código fosse isso:

```
    out: for (int i = 0; i < jogadores.length; i++) {
        boolean adicionar = lerBoolean(
                input,
                "Deseja adicionar jogador? sim ou não",
                "Não entendi. Vamos tentar novamente.");
        if (!adicionar) break;
        System.out.println("Digite um nome");
        String nome = input.next();
        jogadores[i] = new Jogador(nome);
    }
```

Esse método `lerBoolean` seria assim:

```
    public static boolean lerBoolean(String mensagem, String naoEntendi) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(mensagem);
            String resposta = input.next().toUpperCase().trim();
            if (resposta.startsWith("S")) return true;
            if (resposta.startsWith("N")) return false;
            System.out.println(naoEntendi);
        }
    }
```

## Outras melhorias possíveis no código

Para não ficar limitado ao número 2 de jogadores, sugiro trocar isso:

```
Jogador[] jogadores = new Jogador[2];
```

Por isso:

```
List<Jogador> jogadores = new ArrayList<>();
```

E então, o código do laço fica assim:

```
   while (true) {
        boolean adicionar = lerBoolean(
                input,
                "Deseja adicionar jogador? sim ou não",
                "Não entendi. Vamos tentar novamente.");
        if (!adicionar) break;
        System.out.println("Digite um nome");
        String nome = input.next();
        jogadores.add(new Jogador(nome));
    }
```

Isso também elimina a variável `i`, permite você ter qualquer quantidade de jogadores e te livra da necessidade de verificar se há algum `null` em algum lugar do array. O segundo laço poderia então ser simplificado para isso:

```
for (Jogador j : jogadores) {
    boolean aceita = lerBoolean(
                input,
                j.getNome() + " Deseja apostar? sim ou não",
                "Não entendi. Vamos tentar novamente.");
    if (aceita) {
        apostar(j);
    } else if (j.getSemapostas() == 3) {
        System.out.println("Você está sem apostar há três rodadas.");
        apostar(j);
    } else {
        j.SemApostar();
    }
}
```

Dá para melhor isso colocando o método `apostar` dentro da classe `Jogador`, afinal quem realiza a após é o jogador, e portanto o método é dele. Com isso `apostar(j);` torna-se `j.apostar();`. Também sugiro renomear o método `getSemapostas` para `getSemApostas`, `SemApostar` para `semApostar` e `Rodar` para `rodar`, pois a convenção dita que a inicial de cada palavra (exceto a primeira) no nome do método deveria ser maiúscula.

Isso também pode ser otimizado de uma outra forma: Se o jogador já está há três rodadas sem apostar, então nem precisa pedir se ele vai querer ou não apostar, pois ele é forçado a fazê-lo:

```
for (Jogador j : jogadores) {
    if (j.semApostas() == 3) {
        System.out.println("Você está sem apostar há três rodadas.");
        apostar(j);
    } else {
        boolean aceita = lerBoolean(
                input,
                j.getNome() + " Deseja apostar? sim ou não",
                "Não entendi. Vamos tentar novamente.");
        if (aceita) {
            apostar(j);
        } else {
            j.SemApostar();
        }
    }
}
```

Aliás, seria interessante colocar isso como um método a parte `fazerApostas`. Vou abordar isso mais abaixo.

No método `Rodar`, esse laço:

```
    for (int i =0;i<jogadores.length;i++){
        Jogador JG = jogadores[i];
```

Fica assim:

```
    for (Jogador jg : jogadores) {
```

Entretanto, o método `apostar(Jogador)` tem problemas também. Tanto o método `main` quanto o `apostar(Jogador)` estão criando `Scanner`s diferentes e você só deveria ter um `Scanner`. O método `apostar` também está criando uma `Banca` ao invés de usar uma já existente e uma outra banca está sendo usada no método `Rodar`. Assim sendo, a `Banca` e o `input` deveriam ser criados no `main` e repassados a ambos os métodos.

Copiar e colar código é uma das piores práticas de programação existentes. Evite ao máximo fazer isso. No seu método `Rodar` há o seguinte código copiado e colado um monte de vezes:

```
                if(<alguma condição>){ // acertou
                    if(banc.getBudget()>= JG.getFichasApostadas()*2){// verifique o budget do banco (Suficiente)
                        banc.pagarJogador(JG.getFichasApostadas()*2);// Atualise o budget do banco
                        JG.ganharFichas(JG.getFichasApostadas()*2); //paga joador
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                        System.out.println(numero + " "+cor);
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome() + " acertou");
                        System.out.println("-------------------------");
                        System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                    }else                               // verifique o budget do banco (Insuficiente)
                        System.out.println(JG.getNome() + " deixou a banca pobre");

                }
                else{                           //não acertou
                    banc.ganharDoJogador(JG.getFichasApostadas());
                    System.out.println(JG.getNome());
                    System.out.println(numero + " "+cor);
                    System.out.println(JG.getNome() +" não acertou");
                    System.out.println("-------------------------");
                    System.out.println("saldo atual : " + JG.getFichas());
                }
```

Podemos reestruturar esse método gravando a condição do `if` em uma variável e então fazer essa lógica apenas depois (atentando-se ao fato de que o fator de multiplicação pode ser 2 ou 36, dependendo do caso). Quase todo o conteúdo desse método `Rodar` pode ser inteiramente movido para a classe `Banca`:

```
public void pagar(Roleta r, Jogador j) {
    System.out.println(j.getNome());
    int numero = r.getNumero();
    String cor = r.getCor();
    System.out.println(numero + " " + cor);
    String apostado = j.getAposta();
    boolean cond
            = apostado.equals("par") ? numero > 0 && numero % 2 == 0
            : apostado.equals("impar") ? numero > 0 && numero % 2 == 1
            : apostado.equals("vermelho") ? cor.equals("vermelho")
            : apostado.equals("preto") ? cor.equals("preto")
            : apostado.equals("menor") ? numero >= 1 && numero <= 18
            : apostado.equals("maior") ? numero >= 19 && numero <= 36
            : apostado.equals("numero") ? numero == j.getNumeroAposta();
    boolean fator = apostado.equals("numero") ? 36 : 2;

    int aposta = j.getFichasApostadas();
    int premio = aposta * fator;
    int budget = getBudget();
    if (premio > budget) premio = budget;

    if (!cond) {
        ganharDoJogador(aposta);
        System.out.println(j.getNome() + " não acertou");
    } else if (getBudget() >= premio) {
        pagarJogador(premio);
        j.ganharFichas(premio);
        System.out.println(j.getNome() + " acertou");
        if (premio == budget) System.out.println(j.getNome() + " deixou a banca pobre.");
    }

    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    System.out.println("Saldo atual: " + j.getFichas());
}
```

Na sua classe `Jogo`, restaria isso no método `rodar`:

```
public static void rodar(Roleta r, Banca b, List<Jogador> jogadores) {
    r.rodar();
    for (Jogador j : jogadores) {
        b.pagar(r, j);
    }
}
```

Observe que coloquei a roleta e a banca como parâmetros, afinal de contas, você pode querer fazer várias rodadas com os mesmos jogadores, a mesma banca e a mesma roleta. Aliás, isso sugere que esses são os atributos de `Jogo` (e esse método seria de instância), e portanto a sua classe `Jogo` fica na sua forma final como está abaixo:

## Como fica no final

```
public class Jogo {
    private final List<Jogador> jogadores;
    private final Roleta roleta;
    private final Banca banca;
    private final Entrada entrada;

    public Jogo(List<Jogador> jogadores) {
        this.jogadores = jogadores;
        this.roleta = new Roleta();
        this.banca = new Banca();
        this.entrada = new Entrada();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Jogador> jogadores = new ArrayList<>();

        while (true) {
            boolean adicionar = entrada.lerBoolean(
                    "Deseja adicionar jogador? sim ou não",
                    "Não entendi. Vamos tentar novamente.");
            if (!adicionar) break;
            String nome = entrada.lerString("Digite um nome");
            jogadores.add(new Jogador(nome));
        }
        Jogo j = new Jogo(jogadores);
        j.jogar();
    }

    private void fazerApostas() {
        for (Jogador j : jogadores) {
            if (j.semApostas() == 3) {
                System.out.println("Você está sem apostar há três rodadas.");
                j.apostar(entrada, banca);
            } else {
                boolean aceita = entrada.lerBoolean(
                        j.getNome() + " Deseja apostar? sim ou não",
                        "Não entendi. Vamos tentar novamente.");
                if (aceita) {
                    j.apostar(entrada, banca);
                } else {
                    j.semApostar();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void jogar() {
        rodar();
    }

    public void rodar() {
        fazerApostas();
        roleta.rodar();
        for (Jogador j : jogadores) {
            banca.pagar(roleta, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Usar as strings "par", "impar", "vermelho", etc. para denotar o tipo de aposta é um saco. Use `enum`s e observe que ele já encapsula a lógica para determinar se o número da roleta é ou não aceito:

```
public enum Cor {
    VERMELHO, PRETO;
}
```

```
public enum TipoAposta implements Regra {
    PAR((n, c, a) -> n > 0 && n % 2 == 0),
    IMPAR((n, c, a) -> n > 0 && n % 2 == 1),
    VERMELHO((n, c, a) -> c == Cor.VERMELHO),
    PRETO((n, c, a) -> c == Cor.PRETO),
    MENOR((n, c, a) -> n >= 1 && n <= 18),
    MAIOR((n, c, a) -> n >= 19 && n <= 36),
    NUMERO((n, c, a) -> n == a);

    private final Regra regra;

    private TipoAposta(Regra regra) {
        this.regra = regra;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validar(int numero, Cor cor, int apostado) {
        return regra.validar(numero, cor, apostado);
    }

    public int getFator() {
        return this == NUMERO ? 36 : 2;
    }
}
```

```
public interface Regra {
    public boolean validar(int numero, Cor cor, int apostado);
}
```

Com isso, o método `pagar` da classe `Banca` fica assim:

```
public void pagar(Roleta r, Jogador j) {
    System.out.println(j.getNome());
    int numero = r.getNumero();
    Cor cor = r.getCor();
    System.out.println(numero + " " + cor);
    TipoAposta apostado = j.getAposta();
    boolean cond = apostado.validar(numero, cor, j.getNumeroAposta());
    int aposta = j.getFichasApostadas();
    int premio = aposta * apostado.getFator();
    int budget = getBudget();
    if (premio > budget) premio = budget;

    if (!cond) {
        ganharDoJogador(aposta);
        System.out.println(j.getNome() + " não acertou.");
    } else if (getBudget() >= premio) {
        pagarJogador(premio);
        j.ganharFichas(premio);
        System.out.println(j.getNome() + " acertou.");
        if (premio == budget) System.out.println(j.getNome() + " deixou a banca pobre.");
    }

    System.out.println("-------------------------");
    System.out.println("Saldo atual: " + j.getFichas());
}
```

O tipo do atributo `cor` na classe `Roleta` passa a ser `Cor` ao invés de `String`. O tipo do atributo `aposta` na classe `Jogador` passa a ser `TipoAposta` ao invés de `String`. Os respectivos getters e setters também mudam da mesma forma.

Aproveitamos também para centralizar todas as operações de leitura de dados em uma classe `Entrada`:

```
public class Entrada {

    private final Scanner input;

    public Entrada() {
        this.input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public String lerString(String mensagem) {
        System.out.println(mensagem);
        return input.next();
    }

    public int lerInt(String mensagem) {
        System.out.println(mensagem);
        return input.nextInt();
    }

    public boolean lerBoolean(String mensagem, String naoEntendi) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(mensagem);
            String resposta = input.next().toUpperCase().trim();
            if (resposta.startsWith("S")) return true;
            if (resposta.startsWith("N")) return false;
            System.out.println(naoEntendi);
        }
    }

    public TipoCor lerTipo(String mensagem, String naoEntendi) {
        List<String> opcoes = Arrays.asList(escolhas);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(mensagem);
            String resposta = input.next().toUpperCase().trim();
            try {
                return TipoCor.valueOf(resposta);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException) {
                System.out.println(naoEntendi);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Na classe `Jogador`, o método `apostar` fica assim:

```
public void apostar(Entrada entrada, Banca b) {
    if (getFichas() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Você não tem fichas!");
        semApostar();
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("Apostar");
    System.out.println("--------");
    String msg = "Par ou impar\nPreto ou vermelho\nNumero\nMaior ou Menor";
    TipoAposta aposta = entrada.lerTipo(msg, "Não entendi. Vamos tentar novamente.");
    setAposta(aposta);

    System.out.println("Insire o valor (número de fichas): ");
    int fichas = entrada.lerInt();
    setFichasApostadas(fichas);
    b.ganharDoJogador(fichas);
    if (aposta == TipoAposta.NUMERO) {
        System.out.println("Qual número deseja apostar?");
        setNumeroAposta(entrada.lerInt());
    }
}
```

Deve ser possível fazer mais um monte de simplificações e melhorias, mas você não deu o código de `Banca`, `Roleta` e `Jogador` para isso.

Note que na classe `Jogo` eu coloquei um método `jogar` que por enquanto apenas chama `rodar`. Nesse método é que você vai fazer a lógica para realizar diversas rodadas até que todos os jogadores exceto um estejam sem fichas.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei se vai ajudar, mas eu faria o codigo assim: Assim você tem certeza que cairá no loop pelo menos.

```
 String option;
        do{
            System.out.println("Deseja adicionar jogador? sim ou não");
            option = input.next();
            if (option.equals("sim")){
                System.out.println("Digite um nome");
                String nome = input.next();
                Jogador J = new Jogador(nome);
                jogadores[i] = J;
            }
        }while(option.equals("sim"));
```